# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron N7110

Tags: system-installation, usb, dell

I recently got a used Inspiron machine that came with Windows 7. For some reason, it won't boot to windows successfully, only to Recovery. I found the license key underneath the laptop, so I tried re-installing Windows 7. That didn't work because it didn't recognize a way to install the system partition.

So I went to Ubuntu. I have an 8GB Flash drive with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it. I also have an available MacBook air. I successfully booted from the USB on the MacBook, but for some reason, I get this message when booting to the USB on the Inspiron. I get this error message:

> An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. Press any key to restart

There are 2 USB 3.0 ports, which do not recognize the USB drive, a regular USB port, and a USB/eSATA port. I usually use the USB/eSATA port when booting from other sources.

Thanks.

P.S. - I know I got the correct iso... I needed 64-Bit so I got 64-bit.

Comment: Why does my answer keep getting deleted? I'm trying to say that it's not possible to do it!

Comment: Because it's not an *answer*. If you have more information to add to your question please [edit] it into the existing question. Thanks :)

Comment: Your answer also claims that because there's no UEFI you can't install Ubuntu.  Ubuntu still supports legacy MBR mode, so that 'answer' is actually NOT an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you burn the ISO right? You can't extract the iso directly. Use this tool to burn it to your USB drive. https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Make sure the Usb has at least 6gb of space.
More common problems are that your ram is malfunctioning. Take the ram out and put it into separate slots. To make sure your motherboard isn't malfunctioning take out the ram and gpu if you have one and turn on your computer. If it beeps your motherboardis working.

BEFORE that, go into the bios menu and go to the boot tab. If it doesn't show up there,.then use the methods above

Comment: It's set up right, otherwise, it wouldn't boot to Ubuntu on my Mac from the same USB.